# Clicking on project kanban opening tasks, wants to change it - odoo

Tags: javascript, odoo-8

**Problem:**

While clicking on project kanban view it will redirect to **project.tasks** kanban view instead of opening project from view.

**What I want to do:**

I would like to open form view of the project instead of tasks kanban. Is there any easy solution for this?

**What I have done so far:**

I have found the project.js file in project module in which one function was written but I really don't understand what they have done in that.

```
openerp.web_kanban.KanbanRecord.include({
        on_card_clicked: function() {
            if (this.view.dataset.model === 'project.project') {
                this.$('.oe_kanban_project_list a').first().click();
            } else {
                this._super.apply(this, arguments);
            }
        },
    });
```

What I need to change to achieve my purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Either you can direct change in the on_card_clicked function or override it to your custom module to open Project form view when clicking on the Kanban view of the project, using below one change in the method. Just need to replace the **o_project_kanban_boxes** keyword with **o_kanban_card_manage_section**

```
openerp.web_kanban.KanbanRecord.include({
    on_card_clicked: function() {
        if (this.view.dataset.model === 'project.project') {
            this.$('.o_kanban_card_manage_section a').first().click();
        } else {
            this._super.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    },
});
```